# Visual Studio 2015 'Show potential fixes' keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard, ide

When VS2015 detects an error in a line of code it displays a red squiggle. When you hover the *mouse cursor* over that it displays a lightbulb and a error popup indicating what is wrong, at that point you can press CTRL+'.' to show 'potential fixes' and select one.

The problem is that moving the *keyboard cursor* over the red squiggle and pressing CTRL+'.' does nothing at all. The CTRL+'.' keyboard shortcut only works when the lightbulb and error popup are already visible, and the only way to make the lightbulb and popup visible are to hover the *mouse cursor* over the red squiggle, at which point (since you've already had to grab the mouse) it makes the use of the CTRL+'.' keyboard shortcut rather pointless.

So my question is: How do I access the 'Show potential fixes' feature using the keyboard only?

VS2015 Pro Update 3, Resharper installed but disabled. Win7 x64.

Answer (score 6):

Using Shift+Alt+F10 to have a try.

Comment: I tried that but it dodn't work. The only way I've managed to access the 'potential fixes' view with the keyboard is with Resharper installed. Even a new install of VS2017 I can't access it with the keyboard.

Comment: Not for me it doesn't. What is the keyboard shortcut called so that I can manually bind it? Opening Tools->Options->Keyboard and in the 'Show commands containing' field entering 'potential' or 'fixes' lists zero commands.

Comment: Show commands containing: 'EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.QuickActionsForPosition' worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

go to Keyboard Shortcuts and search about Quick Fix and change with any shortcut you want probably will find it CTRL+'.'  by default
hope this answer help anyone.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose, you didn't disable ReSharper.

To solve your issue:

1. Go to `Resharper / Options / Environment / Editor / Visual Studio Features`
2. And uncheck `Hide Visual Studio light bulb`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change that keyboard shortcut. As an example use "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>" Instead of "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>" for C# Quick Actions on Visual Studio.

- Inside Visual Studio, go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd>
- Search for keyboard and you will see the **"Keyboard"** section under **"Environment"** pane
- Search for "quickaction" and apply the "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>"

[image: View.QuickActions]

Now you can use "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>" to show 'potential fixes' and select one.